# Getting Error : Error: Cannot find module 'datadog-lambda-js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, datadog

**Overview**

I've been trying to get datadog to work with my lambda functions. We're using serverless framework. Our main objective here is to send some custom metrics to datadog from our lambdas. To do this, we're using the Serverless plugin for datadog (**serverless-plugin- datadog**), along with **datadog-lambda-js** Library (Included references in the end). One last thing to include is, we are using webpack to build our services.

**Issues and Errors:**

1. Running the serverless-services locally works perfectly fine (we install datadog-lambda-js on dev dependencies). All our metrics are being sent to Datadog.
2. However when we push it to Lambda, We get errors from all services saying **Error: Cannot find module 'datadog-lambda-js**. We see this on the lambda logs.
3. We've used all steps and methods available to fix this, we also know webpack has some issues with datadog, but we've followed steps to handle this also ([check this](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/guide/serverless_tracing_and_webpack/)). Also, before deploying it to lambdas, we remove the datadog-lambda-js dependencies package.json, but still no luck.

I'll drop the code blocks below for reference. Please let me know if I've missed anything.

```js
// serverless.yml

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-plugin-resource-tagging
  - serverless-dynamo-stream-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-datadog
  
custom:
  serviceName: <my-service>
  datadog:
    addExtension: true
    addLayers: true
    apiKey: <my-dd-key>
    # flushMetricsToLogs: false
    enabled: true
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: /webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
      forceExclude: 
        - datadog-lambda-js
    packagerOptions: 
      scripts:
        - rm -rf node_modules/datadog-lambda-js
    packager: npm
```

```js
// file that sends distribution metrics
const { datadog, sendDistributionMetric, sendDistributionMetricWithDate } = require('datadog-lambda-js');

exports.hello = async function hello() {
    console.log("Running metrics")
    sendDistributionMetricWithDate(
      <my-metric-name>,       // Metric name
      1,
      new Date(Date.now()),                            // Metric value
      "tag1:T1",
      "tag2:T2",  // Associated tags
      
    );
    console.log("Closing metrics")
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "hello, dog!",
    };
  }
```

Apart from this, We have also excluded datadog-lambda-js from webpack : **externals: [nodeExternals(), "datadog-lambda-js"]**

Would appreciate any help on this.

**References:**

1. [Sending Custom Metric](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/custom_metrics)
2. [Using Datadog with Node.js Serverless application](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/nodejs/?tab=serverlessframework)
3. [Webpack changes to run DD library](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/guide/serverless_tracing_and_webpack/)

Comment: If you remove all the webpack configuration does it work, and when I say "remove the webpack configuration", I mean "deploy the app successfully to lambda without using webpack"

Comment: Hi @WarrenParad 
In that case, The build fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Datadog lambda layer to your lambda function. This should happen when you install the serverless framework plugin via `serverless plugin install --name serverless-plugin-datadog`.

Alternately, find the ARN from [the docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/nodejs/?tab=custom), then add it to your lambda function. [This blog post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/datadog-lambda-layer/#set-up-the-datadog-layer) has more detailed instructions on adding a layer via the AWS console.

Comment: Thanks for this @bwest 
But the DD lambda layers are already added. I also tried to use these DD lambda layers on another (manually created) lambdas by using it's ARN, and they work with datadog-lambda-js lib. But the primary lambdas still throw the same errors.